# Monotouch 4.9 Alpha with MonoDevelop 2.8 Alpha: socket error starting simulator

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm doing some testing with MonoDevelop 2.8 Alpha and MonoTouch 4.9 alpha to check out some of the new UI controllers Apple offers with iOS 5.

When trying to launch my app, all I get in MonoDevelop is:

```
Socket error while connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 10001: Connection refused
```